# In Romans 7:18 why is the phrase "that is,in my flesh" bracketed in the NKJV?

Tags: romans, translation-philosophy, paul, esv

Romans 7:18 NKJV

> For I know that in me ***(that is, in my flesh)*** nothing good
> dwells; for to will is present with me, but how to perform what is
> good I do not find.

But in other modern translations it is not bracketed

Romans 7:18 ESV

> For I know that nothing good dwells in me, that is, ***in my flesh***.
> For I have the desire to do what is right, but not the ability to
> carry it out.

Romans 7:18 DARBY

> For I know that in me, that is, ***in my flesh***, good does not
> dwell: for to will is there with me, but to do right [I find] not.

Romans 7:18 YLT

> for I have known that there doth not dwell in me, that is, ***in my
> flesh***, good: for to will is present with me, and to work that which
> is right I do not find,

Why is this phrase bracketed in the NKJV?

Answer (score 5):

The punctuation in the NKJV of bracketing the phrase in Rom 7:18, "that is, in my flesh" suggests it is simply a parenthetical remark.  Other versions simply use two commas rather than parentheses.

The use of the parentheses is not intended to suggest that the phrase is spurious.  The text of Rom 7:18 is undisputed.

The convention in the NLJV for showing added text by the translators is the same as in the KJV - italic type face such as in Rom 7:8, "manner of evil".

Thus, the parentheses in the NKJV of Rom 7:18 is unremarkable.

Answer (score 2):

In NKJV (Rom. 7:18) round parentheses are a punctuation matter of how non-restrictive the phrase is.  It does not indicate a lack of confidence in the underlying Greek text.  A restrictive phrase has no punctuation.  Non-restrictive has punctuation setting it apart, starting with commas.  Round parentheses () means it's even less essential to the meaning of what's modified; just there in case you don't understand.

NA28 uses square brackets [] for text that has poor textual support, but enough they consider worth giving the reader the option to consider.  I'm not aware of any English translations using this.